# Adding a polyline in a GoogleMap (android)

Tags: android

I`m working with a Navigation Drawer Activity.
In MainActivity I have a PolylineOptions object, called "options", instaced in "OnCreate()". In MainActivity I also have a location listener, where I have:

```
options.add(new LatLng(cell.getLatitude(), cell.getLongitude()));
```

cell is a custom object. Those methods are tested and they are working fine.
In a fragment I have:

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mapa, container, false);
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

main.options.color(Color.RED);
main.options.width(5);
main.options.visible(true);
mMap.addPolyline(main.options);
mMap.setMapType(mapType);
Log.i("MapType", ""+mMap.getMapType());
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 17);
mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
Location myLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        Log.i("Chamada: ", "Localização do Google map alterada");
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
        location.getLongitude()), 17);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }
});
```

Where "main" is a instance of MainActivity.

The polyline isn't appearing when I run the app. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You set only one `LatLng` value in the optins object. This means that will be [added a vertex to the end of the polyline being built.](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions.html#add(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng))

Try to inform a second location and create the line between two points:

```
options.add(new LatLng(cell.getLatitude(), cell.getLongitude()), new LatLng(lat, lng));
```